# Column names not showing correctly in R

Tags: r, dataframe

The column names of my `data.frame` are: `Q1    Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  Q6`.

I wonder why when I read in my data into R the first column name shows as `1..Q1`?

Note: I'm using `R version 4.0.0`.

```
read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/v/main/fa.csv")

  ï..Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 Q6
1     6  5  4  8  6  2
2     8  7  2  7  5  3
3     9  8  1  9  7  1
4     5  4  5  9  7  1
5     4  3  6  9  7  1
6     7  6  3  7  5  3
7     3  2  7  7  5  3
```

Comment: Can you show us a small extract from your csv?  It looks like you may have row numbers.

Comment: @Elin, [HERE](https://github.com/rnorouzian/v/blob/main/fa.csv) is the data. However, I'm not sure what you mean because I already am showing the data above.

Comment: This has to do with the row number on the column headers row. It happens from time to time to see that "feature".

Comment: You're showing the data after it has been processed and as you can see there is a new column with row numbers added.  When I run your one line of code i'm not getting the extra variable.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, not sure what the fix is, I appreciate a formal answer so i can test and accept.

Comment: It should be an encoding issue, try `fileEncoding = 'UTF-8-BOM'`. But like @Elin I cannot reproduce the problem, the data is being read in correctly.

Comment: Like @RuiBarradas said, you need to define the `fileEncoding`, otherwise R reads in the UTF8 BOM as unwanted characters.

Comment: To help us repro this, what OS and locale are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`readr` part of `tidyverse` can also be used

```
read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/v/main/fa.csv")
# A tibble: 7 x 6
     Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4    Q5    Q6
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     6     5     4     8     6     2
2     8     7     2     7     5     3
3     9     8     1     9     7     1
4     5     4     5     9     7     1
5     4     3     6     9     7     1
6     7     6     3     7     5     3
7     3     2     7     7     5     3
```